# How to intercept static in express?

Tags: node.js, express

In my nodejs application, I have set the static directory to be:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/mydir'));
```

Inside that mydir directory, I have an index.html. I noticed when i have a route below the line above:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {  
  console.log("here")
  res.send('test');
});
```

This does not do anything, though the index.html does show up! I want to be able to do something before it returns. So above that I have:

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
  console.log("do something here");
});
```

However, the "do something here" never gets fired. I want to check the headers of the request before I do something. What do I need to do? Note that i have a bunch of images after, I really don't want console.log("here") or "do something here" to be logged multiple times, I just want to do it once for only when the user loads "index.html" or calls on any specific routes.

Comment: Would it be possible to nest the static app.use inside the other one? e.g

    app.use(function(req, res) {
      if(something){
         app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/mydir'));
     }
    });

Comment: Im open to suggestions, not sure what you mean by that. I just tried shoving it in, but nothing is returning... its just stuck at loading circle. I see the "do something here".

Comment: Something like this - https://jsfiddle.net/de5auks3/

Comment: Okay, when I add a next at the bottom, it works. My problem is, I have a lot of images, etc referenced in my index.html page. I want to secure specific routes. I just see like hundreds of console.log's because it's doing that for every single request matching /* i think.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer? I'm finding at hard to fully understand what you want to happen, but can't get working. Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, that worked. Ashley, can you post? I'll accept your answer since you were first.

Comment: You will generally find that your life is a lot simpler if you put your static HTML files in a different directory than your dynamic ones.  Then, your `express.static()` routes won't ever accidentally server a file meant to be dynamically modified.  They can all appear to be coming from the same path in the browser, your routes can just handle them differently and source them from different locations on your hard disk.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is place your custom middleware *before* the `express.static()` middleware. For example:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('do something here');
  next(); // Continue on to the next middleware/route handler
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/mydir'));
```

Or if you want to limit it to a specific path:

```
app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('do something here');
  next(); // Continue on to the next middleware/route handler
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/mydir'));
```

Comment: Good spot, I think it was perhaps due to the lack of next() in his final middleware.